# how to share particular url in facebook

Tags: php, facebook

i have created some pages, which have multiple images.
now i want to share those pages on facebook, which shows url with image
please give me some idea.

I tried with facebook sharer.php

but it is not working

Comment: i tried with anchor tag link of facebook sharer.php?u="abc"

Comment: Update your question to show what you have tried and how it didn't work.

Comment: stackoverflow.com doesn't allow me to ask question with http

Comment: Sorry then but as I cannot see what you have actually done, I cannot explain what is wrong with it

Answer (score 0):

Facebook automatically detects images from your page, when you share it and displays them in the timeline. But there's a way to use particular image, when sharing links:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="YOUR_TITLE_HERE">
<meta property="og:description" content="YOUR_CONTENT_HERE">
<meta property="og:image" content="PATH_TO_IMAGE">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="YOUR_IMAGE_WIDTH">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="YOUR_IMAGE_HEIGHT">
```

The path to the image must be absolute AND jpg. Like "http://yourwebsite.com/image.jpg". 
Width and height values must be without "px" at the end.

You can use Open Graph Debugger in Facebook to test your links:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/